# Need help creating a drawing tool for pixel drawing using mouse drag and release in Javascript

Tags: javascript, click, addeventlistener, onmouseover, onmousedown

Oh hey! I am a JavaScript beginner playing around with DOM and I am currently facing an issue for which I have been unable to find a solution. What I've wanted is to paint each sqaure divs acting as pixels/cells and anytime you clicked and/or dragged the mouse, it'll change each div's background color as if it's like standard painting application. In the first code block below is what I ended up using but it isn't what I wanted, it can only paint each individual pixels/cells by clicking one on one. I attempted using `EventListener` with `onmousedown` or `mouseover` nested inside an `EventListener` with `Click`. However, this was unsuccessful. I had hoped that after clicking, the next `EventListener` would be detected and I would be able to draw like many other standard drawing apps. Would appreciate if anyone point me in the right direction.

```
 document.querySelectorAll(".PixelBoxes").forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log(colorPicker.color.hexString);
        element.style.backgroundColor = colorPicker.color.hexString;
    })
  });
```

This is the messy unsuccessful code I tried to describe earlier.

```
element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(colorPicker.color.hexString);
    element.style.backgroundColor = colorPicker.color.hexString;

    document.querySelectorAll(".PixelBoxes").forEach( element => {
        element.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
          element.style.backgroundColor = colorPicker.color.hexString;
        })
    })
}
```

Here's my codepen to see everything in works and the part I'm working at related to this post is on line 126 of JS section (CSS responsive design may be little wonky): https://codepen.io/DawnofSouls/pen/GRXeQRo

As stated before, what I've wanted is to create a some sort of drawing feature like many standard drawing applications have. At first, I've tried putting a `onmousedown` or `mouseover` inside of `eventlisten click` to achieve the standard brush/pencil tool that ended up not working the way I wanted. It instead painted each pixels nonstop even after letting go off the mouse.

Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No judgment here only tips to help you ;)

At start you need to do pseudo code , and realize wich function you need to avoid spagetti code while you begin to type and debug .
Creating a "the_thing_i_want_to_do" library if you like .

You need to detect when clic is released and apply color only if clic is on like :

```
    var mouseDown = 0;
    document.body.onmousedown = function() { 
      ++mouseDown;
    }
    document.body.onmouseup = function() {
      --mouseDown;
    }
```

So inside:
`element.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {`

you can use it like this :

```
    if(mouseDown){
  // change color of destination 
    }
```

Comment: Interesting we are still using "var" as I've been told to not to use that but hey, it works. I just changed it to "let". Appreciate it! And thank you for reminded me of Psuedo code, I really need to do that haha.